# python - plotly save table without whitespace

Tags: python, plotly

i generate a table in python with plotly and i save it as png . but the saved png has a lot of whitespace. i there a solution that the png/or image is "filled" or "Full-screen/image". [image]

i generate the table with:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='example_table.png', format='png')
```

thanks for ideas and solutions. greets alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go    
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    margin = {'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0},
    height = 125
)
fig.write_image("fig1.png")
```

the `update_layout` will help you to fix the height and weight of the chart.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi Subbo, thank you for your solution. better than mine! i will use the images to implement them into a pdf. so the white space around the table is still to much!

Comment: thank you for the update. i will look to calculate the hight automatically by the rows of the frame

Comment: @Alex did you ever figure out how to dynamically set the height?

Comment: @PirateX: yes, i take the lenght of the data:

rows_in_df = len(data) # to calculate high of table

and then:

fig.update_layout(width=2900, height=rows_in_df * 30 + 100) 

30 depend on the  cell hight and 100 of the header hight

Comment: exactly what I need. Thanks!