# Remove whitespace below Plotly Graph Object Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python

I'm building a simple Plotly table with margins as 0 but the output still spits out huge whitespace at the bottom of it. I tried using height to set adjustment but that's static and will not change if the number of rows change in data as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334713/4046274)

Code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

layout = go.Layout(
  margin=go.layout.Margin(
        l=0, #left margin
        r=0, #right margin
        b=0, #bottom margin
        t=0,  #top margin
        pad=0
    )
)
    
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                     cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                         ],layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Result
[image]

How do I get rid of that whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the graph size to the desired size in both width and height by setting the automatic setting to False.

```
fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width=250,
                  height=120
                 )
```

[image]